# Download files from GUN

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, base64, gun

trying to download a file that uploads to GUN with this code

```
 <p>Drag & drop videos, songs, or images! <input type="file" multiple></p>

<button  id="btn" /></button>


<script>
var gun = Gun(location.origin + '/gun');

$('html').upload(function resize(eve, up){
  if(up){ return up.shrink(eve, resize, 1024) }
  var b64 = (eve.base64 || ((eve.event || eve).target || eve).result || eve);
  gun.get('test').get(eve.id).put(b64);
});

gun.get('test').map().on(function(data){
  if(!data){ return }
  var type = data.split(';')[0], ui;
  if(type.indexOf('image') + 1){ ui = $("img").get(0) }
  if(type.indexOf('video') + 1){ ui = $('video').get(0) }
  if(type.indexOf('audio') + 1){ ui = $('audio').get(0) }
  if(!ui){ return }
  $(ui).clone().prependTo('center').get(0).src = data;
})

</script>
```

if id="btn" could be used to trigger the download how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click and "save as".

Or check out this SO:

[How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)